# PHP elseif statement not working

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am currently developing a website with wordpress that uses FSQM Pro quiz plugin. The plugin uses the format string %DESIGNATION% to show the ranking that the user obtained on completing the quiz.

I am trying to write some php that will output different text depending on the ranking that the user reaches but for some reason it just outputs nothing. My code is below, can anyone help?

This bit of code is in a seperate php file `$format_string_components = $this->get_format_string();`

```
<?php
$a="Ranking 1";
$b="Ranking 2";
$c="Ranking 3";
$d="Ranking 4";

if ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $a) {
    echo 'text 1';

} elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $b) {
    echo 'text 2';

} elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $c) {
    echo 'text 3';

} elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $d) {
    echo 'text 4'; 

} else {
    echo '<p>Your result was not found.</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please display this array `$format_string_components`

Comment: @AdamPool Change “ to ".

Comment: Check your quotes. They're messed up. In general it's best to use single quotes, if you don't plan to use any string magic in your strings.

Comment: The opening PHP tag is also `<? php` but it should be `<?php` — if that's what you have on the live site that's definitely a problem.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Thank you, that got it to the point that its now outputting the else function. I guess this is because it doesnt know what `$format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%']` is?

Comment: @AdamPool And because of <?php. I posted a reply with corrections. try again.

Comment: @AdamPool Print the value of format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] and check if any rank.

Comment: @LucasHenrique do you mean `<?php print $format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%']; ?>`? If so, thats not displaying anything.

Comment: @AdamPool The problem is this variable. Make sure the file that contains this value is being called.

Comment: @LucasHenrique I've tried using `include '/wp-content/plugins/wp-fsqm-pro/classes/class-ipt-fsqm-form-elements-data.php';` but I am still getting the else command output. class-ipt-fsqm-form-elements-data.php is the file that declares `$format_string_components = $this->get_format_string();`. Thank you so much for your help by the way, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @AdamPool Check if `$format_string_components` is array in `class-ipt-fsqm-form-elements-data.php`, because your use as such.

Comment: @LucasHenrique `$format_string_components = $this->get_format_string();` and `$format_string_components = array('%DESIGNATION%' => __( 'N/A', 'ipt_fsqm' ),'%DESIGNATIONMSG%' => '',);` are both in `class-ipt-fsqm-form-elements-data.php`

Comment: @AdamPool By what you showed values ​​`Ranking 1`, `Ranking 2`, `Ranking 3`, `Ranking 4` are not in array `$format_string_components`. Why it always goes to the else.

Comment: @LucasHenrique ah that makes sense, so how would I include it in the array? I just tried adding `$format_string_components = array('%DESIGNATION%' => __( 'N/A', 'ipt_fsqm' ),'%DESIGNATIONMSG%' => '','Ranking 1' => $a,'Ranking 2' => $b,'Ranking 3' => $c,'Ranking 4' => $d,);`

Comment: @AdamPool Try `$format_string_components = array('%DESIGNATION%' => __( 'N/A', 'ipt_fsqm', 'Ranking 1','Ranking 2','Ranking 3', 'Ranking 4' ),'%DESIGNATIONMSG%' => '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `“` to `"`. Remove the space `<? php`

```
<?php
    $a="Ranking 1";
    $b="Ranking 2";
    $c="Ranking 3";
    $d="Ranking 4";

    if ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $a) {
        echo "text 1";

    } elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $b) {
        echo "text 2";

    } elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $c) {
        echo "text 3";

    } elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $d) {
        echo "text 4"; 

    } else {
        echo "<p>Your result was not found.</p>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thats got it half way there, thank you. The $format_string_components code is in a file called class-ipt-fsqm-form-elements-data.php and is displayed as $format_string_components = $this->get_format_string();. It still isn't returning a result based on the designation though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working due to the quotes you have used. Change the quotes to " ". Like

```
if ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $a) {
        echo "text 1";

    } elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $b) {
        echo "text 2";

    } elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $c) {
        echo "text 3";

    } elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $d) {
        echo "text 4"; 

    } else {
        echo "<p>Your result was not found.</p>";
    }
```

Also avoid the space in the `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $a="Ranking 1";
    $b="Ranking 2";
    $c="Ranking 3";
    $d="Ranking 4";

    if ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $a) {
        echo 'text 1';

    } elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $b) {
        echo 'text 2';

    } elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $c) {
        echo 'text 3';

    } elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $d) {
        echo 'text 4'; 

    } else {
        echo '<p>Your result was not found.</p>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the quote (") and remove space from

```
<? php
```

Code Use it:

```
<?php
    $a="Ranking 1";
    $b="Ranking 2";
    $c="Ranking 3";
    $d="Ranking 4";

    if ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $a) {
        echo "text 1";
    } elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $b) {
        echo "text 2";
    } elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $c) {
        echo "text 3";
    } elseif ($format_string_components['%DESIGNATION%'] == $d) {
        echo "text 4"; 
    } else {
        echo "<p>Your result was not found.</p>";
    }
?>
```